# Show $F_n$ has a least element and it is prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

let $F_n$ be the set of positive factors of n greater than 1 and  $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Show $F_n$ has a least element and it is prime.

Comment: ? This follows directly from the prime factorization.

Comment: If you understand the terms used here this problem is completely trivial, so: what haven't you understood, and what have you done so far to solve it?

Comment: @Timbuc, let's be civil please.

Comment: @vadim123, I'm sorry if you think I was uncivil above. How come? I'm pointing at what the problem of the OP is *in my opinion* and thus I focus the question in what I think the problem may be. What's uncivic in this? I resent your comment, really.

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE: with out the prime factorization!

Comment: @Timbuc, what is uncivil about your comment is that a person is asking for help and you are calling their problem "completely trivial".

Comment: What would happen if the set of prime factors of a number didn't have a least element?

Comment: @user191436: Do you know the Well Ordering Principle?

Comment: No @vadim123, you misunderstood badly what I wrote: I say that imo the OP must have some problem understanding the terms used in this as otherwise the problem is trivial, and then I asked what problem is (s)he having with that. Again, what's uncivil in this?

Comment: @vadim, then you have your own sense of civil/uncivil, which is different from ther people's; yet the OP hasn't yet even addressed these comments. I think your way of addressing my comment was uncivil, too.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the well ordering principle.

You'll have that $F_n$ has a least element (say $a$).

Now, it all boils down to show that $a$ is prime.

Suppose, on contrary, $a$ isn't prime. Then $\exists b<a$ such that $b|a$ which contradicts the minimality of $a$.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Haha. You should probably undelete your comment. It might help someone else in the future. :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $F_n$ isn't empty ($n\mid n \Rightarrow n \in F_n \Rightarrow |F_n| > 0$) and has the least element. This is due to the fact that $(\forall x \in F_n)(1 < x \leq n \wedge x \in \mathbb{Z})$ and set of [integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer) [is countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set), so $F_n$ must be finite. You can also invoke to [well-ordering principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle).

Assume that $m = \min(F_n)$ and $m$ isn't prime. Then
$\left(\exists~d \in \mathbb{Z}\right)\left(d < m \wedge d | m\right)$.

Using $\left(\forall a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}\right)\left( (a\mid b \wedge b \mid c) \Longrightarrow a \mid c\right)$ we obtain $d \in F_n$.

$$\left(d \mid m \wedge m \mid n \right)\Longrightarrow(d \mid n) \Longrightarrow d \in F_n$$

$\left(d < m \wedge d\in F_n \right)$ is contrary to the assumption $m = \min(F_n)$, so $m$ is prime.

Answer (score 0):

let
$F_n=\{x:x|n ~and~x>0\}$

by WOA $F_n$ has a least element be $q$.

Suppose $q$ isn't a prime.

Which means it can be factored in to a prime $q=p_1k $ by doing this repeatedly the least element of $F_n$ should be a prime.